# How to fix "The extension is incompatible with the targeted version of Visual Studio" (vs 2022)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, marketplace, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to update my published Visual Studio extension to the 2022 version, [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayBelyh.ExtendedVisioAddinProject)

The problem is: I keep getting (when attempting to update on the marketplace).

> The extension is incompatible with the targeted version of Visual
> Studio. More info at https://aka.ms/ExtensionSdkErrors

Locally, the extension installs and runs fine (on 2022 as well), this version that can be downloaded from the "[GitHub releases](https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/releases/tag/1.2.4)", and there are no blocking messages when building it as well from the analyzers.

The link in the error message says that the extension should be using the latest version of the VisualStudio.Sdk (version 17). The thing is, it does!

Any suggestion what I could look at to make the submission succeed?

Extension has two bundled child project templates inside, and one template wizard (in addition to the SDK it has a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamplateInterface v.17), because SDK does not seem to have this package bundled.

Full source code:
https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/tree/vs2022

Comment: I get it for my extensions too. Luckily it is just a warning, so I ignore it.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thank you, it worked :) Still wondering what it is this warning about???

Comment: Last year they tried to create a VSIX validator that checked if your extension references any Pre-Visual Studio 2022 assemblies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/migrated-assemblies?view=vs-2022

Comment: Maybe it is that "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamplateInterface" which is NOT part of the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk" package. But any VSIX that has a custom project wizard needs to reference that one, and there does not seem to be a way around this...

Answer (score 0):

Many interop assemblies were embeddable prior to Visual Studio 2022. Beginning in Visual Studio 2022, embedding is no longer required or supported.

try removing the references from the project file https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/blob/master/Wizard/PanelAddinWizard.csproj

- envdte
- EnvDTE80
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop

and use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop

You can refer following list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/migrated-assemblies?view=vs-2022

For more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I have already tried that (before even posting the question) and that didn't work. The working answer is given by Sergey Vlasov in the above comment.